# Infinite loop in rewrite rule: How to prevent www in url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like my site to be accessible by the following two urls only:

```
http://domain.com
http://origin.domain.com
```

But the following rewrite rule gets into an infinite loop:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(origin)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(origin)?\.?domain\.com [NC]
```

Comment: No problem :) +1 for clarity and posting what you already tried.